# Give column the width of container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is there a possibility to give a bootstrap 4 `col` the width of its child, which is a container class?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-secondary m-0 p-0">
            text left
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto bg-primary">
            <div class="container bg-primary m-0 p-0">
                text mid
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col bg-secondary m-0 p-0">
            text right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I basically want to be able to put content on the left and right of a container, but I don't want my container to change in size because of this, because this left and right content won't be present on every page, and I want a consistent container width cross pages.

https://jsfiddle.net/5gt9uoqb/

Update:

Here's an image of what I would like to achieve: [ibb.co/tcKM6S0](https://ibb.co/tcKM6S0) . At the bottom is a 'normal' page, with a centered container. This is a div with the standard container class that ships with bootstrap. At the top is a new page type I would like to create. It should have the exact same container like the other page, but I want to be able to put content in the grey zones, like, for example, some social icons (blue in the img).  Wrapping the normal pages in a column too is not an option in my set up because of other stuff.

Comment: wouldn't you give the left and right columns fixed sizes then - like col-3 or something similar if you don't want them to change size?  Or am I understanding this wrong

Comment: Are you saying you want the container to always have a minimum width and the left/right sides to grow/shrink as needed?

Comment: Well, the container should behave like when he's not inside a column, because on most of my pages, container is not inside a `col`, and I want the container to have same width on every page.

Comment: Try using `container` instead of `container-fluid`? Trying to understand

Comment: I think I didn't explain it very well, or I'm missing something extremely obvious here :). Here's an image of what I would like to achieve: https://ibb.co/tcKM6S0 . At the bottom is a 'normal' page, with a centered container. This is a div with the standard `container` class that ships with bootstrap. At the top is a new page type I would like to create. It should have the exact same container like the other page, but I want to be able to put content in the grey zones, like, for example, some social icons (blue in the img).

Comment: so instead of using col auto, us col-8 or something like that so it is always the same width and add `justify-content-center` to your row classes to center the column when there is no side columns

Comment: Could do that, but, I want it to have the same size on the other pages where the container is not wrapped in a column too. Wrapping those in a column too is not an option in my set up because of other stuff.

Comment: You need to include all this information in your question as it is unclear exactly what you want

Comment: Updated the question with this information.

Comment: Seems to me a better approach is simply to give each of those rows its own container. Nesting containers shouldn't be necessary and is obviously troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

if you know about position property, then you can handle this issue without touching the container class.
For that, you need to a parent class of all child element. I mean after the body tag you take a class and give it position relative the which content you want to be left give it position absolute and left:0px;(you can space from left according to your), and if you want content right then you give it right:0px;

Comment: Not sure if I understand... Could you maybe update the jsfiddle to illustrate your thoughts?